# Codename one Windows UWP build in compliance test on windows store

Tags: codenameone, windows-10-universal

i have made a UWP build with codename one and am trying to put it on the windows store but i get an error under windows compliance test app manifest

the error is:
Levabo takes a dependency on Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package (Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00) framework but is missing the framework dependency declaration in the manifest and Lavabo is the name of the app.

and acording to microsoft what i need to do to fix the error is this:
App manifest must include valid entries for all required fields, please modify the manifest entries listed above. See link below for more information:

but i am not sure where i can change the manifest entries and if it is possible at all.

Codenameone_Setting file:

```
#
#Fri Jul 01 12:46:38 CEST 2016
codename1.arg.java.version=8
codename1.ios.appid=Q5GHSKAL2F.com.duus.levabo
codename1.ios.release.provision=
codename1.arg.rim.obfuscation=false
codename1.arg.ios.newStorageLocation=true
codename1.j2me.nativeTheme=nbproject/nativej2me.res
codename1.arg.ios.project_type=ios
codename1.arg.ios.interface_orientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait\:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
codename1.displayName=Levabo
codename1.android.keystoreAlias=
codename1.arg.windows.makeReleaseAppxbundle=true
codename1.ios.release.certificate=
codename1.android.keystorePassword=
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.arg.android.release=true
codename1.arg.ios.dsym=false
codename1.arg.ios.statusbar_hidden=false
codename1.arg.windows.buildType=Release
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.android.keystore=
codename1.vendor=DuusPartnersPS
codename1.arg.win.ver=8
codename1.ios.certificatePassword=
codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword=
codename1.mainName=MainForm
codename1.windows.certificatePassword=password
codename1.ios.release.certificatePassword=
codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon=false
codename1.ios.debug.certificate=
libVersion=116
codename1.arg.ios.application_exits=false
codename1.secondaryTitle=CodenameOne_Template
codename1.description=
codename1.ios.debug.provision=
codename1.arg.j2me.nativeThemeConst=0
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.version=1.0
codename1.ios.certificate=
codename1.arg.windows.platforms=x86|x64|ARM
codename1.windows.certificate=/Users/thomaswix/Keychain_1.pfx
codename1.icon=icon.png
codename1.arg.windows.appid=DuusPartnersPS.Levabo
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.arg.android.debug=false
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
codename1.arg.ios.testFlight=false
codename1.arg.ios.includePush=false
codename1.packageName=DuusPartnersPS.Levabo
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you build with the Windows store upload setting?  (Ie are you uploading an appxupload file?)

Comment: Yes and the file is of the type .appxupload

Comment: Sounds like it did a debug build.  Strange.  I'll take a look on Monday.  Can you post your codenameone_settings file?  I just need to see properties that start with "windows."

Comment: In the build hint there was windows.buildType Debug but also windows.buildType Release could this be the reason for the error?

Comment: That might cause a problem.  What other windows build hints do you have there "cidename1.arg.windows.*.?

Comment: windows build hints:  
codename1.arg.windows.makeReleaseAppxbundle=true
codename1.arg.windows.buildType=Release
codename1.arg.win.ver=8
codename1.windows.certificatePassword=password
codename1.arg.windows.platforms=x86|x64|ARM
codename1.windows.certificate=/Users/thomaswix/Keychain_1.pfx
codename1.arg.windows.appid=DuusPartnersPS.Levabo

Comment: There must be a bug in our settings UI code.  Try manually changing it so that codename1.arg.windows.makeReleaseAppxbundle=false  (Although I'm puzzled... with your current settings is shouldn't have even produced an appxupload file).

Also.  Do you have any uwp.* properties (i.e. codename1.arg.uwp.*).  These could cause some problems too.

Comment: i stil get this error when i submit to the store: Levabo takes a dependency on Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package (Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00) framework but is missing the framework dependency declaration in the manifest.

Comment: At what point does this error message occur.  I just did a test run with my test app.  I was able to upload to the store and it said "validated".  https://snag.gy/ogce9f.jpg  Does your rejection come later down the line or right when you're trying to perform the upload?
Can you update your question with the current properties?  (e.g. your makeReleaseAppxBundle property should be false.

Comment: i get true the validation also but when i go and press submit to store you get pre-processing with it passes after this you have Certification and this is when it fails.

Comment: Note:  I'm currently working with MS support on this issue.  Will post an update when it is resolved.

Comment: It turns out there was a problem on Microsoft's side that was causing the certification to hang in pre-processing.  The issue was escalated to Engineering.  This morning I received an error 1201 result (which is progress).  Unfortunately there is no description on what error 1201 is, and Microsoft support didn't know either.  So the issue has been escalated to Engineering again.   Will update here when it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with the the .Net native compiler that caused certification to fail, and sometimes hang.  The dotnetnative team worked with me to work around these issues, and I was able to successfully submit an app to the store.  Submission should now work correctly.

Comment: i stil get the error both when i have the argument "windows.UseDotNetNativeToolchain=true" in the codenameone_setting file. also updated codename one to the new version.